# CopyFileEx issue

Tags: c#, winapi

I have problem copying files over a WAN, which are greater than 20MB in size, i.e. they aren't being copied. From what I have been advised, I need to use CopyFileEx rather than CopyTo in FileInfo.

So, I have two questions:

1) Is CopyFileEx the right function to use when copying large files. If not, what should I be using and is there an example code to look at?

2) Can someone please point me in the direction of how to use CopyFileEx in C#?

Comment: Your problem is elsewhere, CopyTo should work fine

Comment: Do you get an error message when the file fails to copy? `CopyTo` will not overwrite an existing file unless you specifically tell it to, but it should throw an exception if you try.

Comment: The article at http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=854 will show you how to use `CopyFileEx` from C#. But you really shouldn't need to.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void FileCopy(string strCopyFile, string strCopyFileTo)
    {
        try
        {
            File.Copy(strCopyFile, strCopyFileTo);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogMessage(ex.Message,Critical);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Andy5 - Please tell us how you fixed it.  That way, you'll help somebody else who might run into the same problem :)